# What does "sleep early" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've got a sentence from a coursebook which goes: "I usually sleep early on Saturdays". What can it possibly mean?

Comment: That sounds like a typo to me. At least in American English it is very unnatural. It might mean that the speaker usually goes to bed earlier than normal on Saturdays. "I usually go to sleep early on Saturdays." Even that sounds less natural than, "I usually go to bed early on Saturdays."

Comment: On the other hand, if the person usually wakes up later than normal on Saturday mornings they may "sleep in on Saturdays"

Comment: I also would like to know whether it is a set phrase/natural way of putting it this way or it is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: there is "sleep in" in a dictionary while there is no sign of "sleep early".. that's why I asked.. I want to make sure..

Comment: It is grammatically fine, and all the words make sense, but without some context to clarify it, I find no intelligible meaning in the sentence.

Comment: the problem is there is no context.. just a sentence..

Comment: This sounds like a back-formation from the idiom "sleep late"... but since "sleep early" is not an established idiom itself, I agree that either this was an editing mistake, or the book's author created an "error" deliberately for discussion or as a counterexample.

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald, I highly disagree. Although read literally, "go to sleep early" is certainly more technically correct than "sleep early", "sleep" is very often used conversationally in place of "go to sleep" in AmE, at least amongst high school- and college- aged people. The only ambiguity I see here is that "early" could be "early in the day" or "early at night".

Comment: Sure. In the sense that one may sleep often. Or sleep poorly. Heck you could even sleep late (later than you meant to). But sleep early? I've never heard such a phrase.

Comment: Because this phrase IS ambiguous as pointed out by Fumblefingers, could you provide the sentences that preceded and followed your example? For example was it taken from a short dialogue or was it an example on how to use adverbs? Could you also provide the name of the coursebook (I suspect it might be by Martin Parrott)

Comment: In English, on Saturdays, we can _sleep late_, or _get up early_. We can also _get up late_, but we don't _sleep early_.

Comment: @Mari-LouA there is no context because there are just separate sentences; the task of the exercise is to put the verbs in brackets into present simple or present continuous - so, as you can see, it has nothing to do with the lexical unit I'm talking about.the book is New Round-Up 3 by Virginia Evans. I've consulted Martin Parrott's Grammar for English Language Teachers, - found it rather helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to voice complete disagreement with everyone who has commented that the sentence is nonsensical despite its structural integrity. As a native American English speaker from the Northeast going to college in the South, it is perfectly common for both myself and my peers to say "sleep" in place of "go to sleep" in conversation.

As evidence, [a Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sleep+early%22+-%22going+to+sleep+early%22+-%22go+to+sleep+early%22+-%22went+to+sleep+early%22+-%22goes+to+sleep+early%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) for "sleep early" that *excludes* "went to", "go to", "goes to", "going to" prefacing the phrase returns 1300+ results at the time of this post. [Searching Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sleep%20early%22%20-%22going%20to%20sleep%20early%22%20-%22go%20to%20sleep%20early%22%20-%22went%20to%20sleep%20early%22%20-%22goes%20to%20sleep%20early%22&oq=%22sleep%20early%22%20-%22going%20to%20sleep%20early%22%20-%22go%20to%20sleep%20early%22%20-%22went%20to%20sleep%20early%22%20-%22goes%20to%20sleep%20early%22) gives 134,000 results (of which, admittedly, many are not good examples, among which is [an article titled "How to Sleep Early for a Night Owl"](http://www.livestrong.com/article/182754-how-to-sleep-early-for-a-night-owl/) and [an article where a commenter notes he/she does not seem to be "wired to sleep early"](http://lifehacker.com/5876083/top-10-tricks-for-better-sleep).

I do agree that it would be technically much more appropriate to say

> I usually *go to* sleep early on Saturdays.

as opposed to

> I sleep early on Saturdays.

because it is unclear whether "early" is referring to sleep as in going to sleep or sleep as in being in the state of being asleep, particularly when the latter is read literally. Idiomatically, however, the latter is fairly commonly used and very commonly understood. The word "crash" is also used in place of "sleep" quite commonly, like so:

> I crash early on Saturdays.

which means *exactly* the same thing. In context, "crash" may be more appropriate for emphasizing just how tired an individual is, but it carries no such connotations by itself.

The reason I mention this is because it is possible - although I have no way of really knowing this - that due to "crash", which is a much more instantaneous and less ambiguous word, being used as a synonym for "sleep", the verb "sleep" has, at least in the vernacular, come to refer to the action of going to sleep.

Comment: There is also [an english.SE thread](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59124/to-sleep-vs-to-go-to-sleep) on this where a Northeast US and an Australian English speaker both note that this usage of "sleep" is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I honestly think half the problem is the word "Saturday".  Substitute, say, "Tuesday" -- **I sleep early on Tuesdays.** -- and the problem goes away.  Going to bed early on Saturdays? Surely that can't be what the speaker meant!  The mind bounces off the notion in incredulity.

Comment: That's quite the good point. The only good context I can think of for using Saturdays would be going to mass (for those unfamiliar, a weekly religious event, usually during Sunday mornings), e.g. "I usually sleep early on Saturdays so I can wake up early to dress and prepare for mass." I'm also a college student, so I'm no stranger to ridiculous sleep schedules, which is possibly why that aspect of the sentence didn't faze me.

Comment: so, if the sentence went like this: I usually sleep early on week days, everything would be ok from the perspective of a Norteast American speaker? @SamuelLijin

Comment: @Yukatan: Presumably you "unaccepted" my answer because you don't like the fact that I'm dismissive of your source. But the fact of the matter is if you said *I usually sleep early on weekdays* most Anglophones (NE Am or anywhere else) would find this "odd", and many would be unsure whether you meant you went to bed early or you got up early (though in practice the one implies the other for 4 out of 5 days). Check Google Books for *"I/he/they/etc. sleep early/late on"* (which will have very few false matches) to underline the reason for the voting pattern on this page.

Comment: the thing is that I can't accept two answers simultaneously; though, God sees, I would love to.. since Samuel Lijin said that that kind of usage was possible.. I accepted it.. not because of the fact that you were dismissive or such like.. @FumbleFingers –  Yukatan

Comment: @Yukatan: Well since Samuel is a native speaker, I can hardly disagree with his claim that this usage is *perfectly common for both him and his peers*. But taking Anglophones as a whole, there's no doubt this is a minority position. On the "normal / ambiguous / unnatural / unacceptable" scale, it's pretty obvious most of us are much further to the right. You should certainly bear that in mind when considering the "idiomatic status" of any other examples in your coursebook.

Comment: I guess that's exactly what I am doing coming here and trying to understand how the English language works.. sure thing I advise my students to use language that is considered to be natural/normal to be on the safe side due to the fact that all of them have to take school state leaving exams.. the reason for me to try and get to the core here is to be able to explain to my students that they can come across all sorts of English even in coursebooks..

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'll add that to me, there's no ambiguity at all - this means that you go to sleep early, plain and simple. If they'd said _I get up early_, or _I wake early_, the meaning would be just as unambiguous - I'm not sure I've ever hear the verb _sleep_ used to mean _wake up_. (Upon reflection, I can see how I can mean both, but I'd never read it as "I go to sleep at the normal time but wake up earlier". I suppose the minimal meaning is that I go to sleep earlier, with additional clarification needed to find out when I wake, if the context doesn't provide.)

Comment: @Yukatan, I suggest you take a look at the [thread I opened on english.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173458/regions-and-reasons-for-the-usage-of-sleep-as-go-to-sleep/) in response to this particular question. There is _undoubtedly_ disagreement as to whether using "sleep" to mean "go to sleep" is an acceptable use of the verb, as there are clearly populations among which this _is_ acceptable and among which this is _not_. The intent of my answer was not so much as to decry FumbleFingers but rather to emphasize this duality.

Comment: @Codeswitcher - BTW, I loved your turn of phrase _"the mind bounces off the notion in incredulity"_.

Answer (score 9):

Per Preston's comment, OP's example is "unnatural" - and since it's not an idiomatic usage, we can't say it has a single fixed unambiguous meaning. The two possibilities are...

> 1: *"I usually **go to** sleep early on Saturdays"*
>    Meaning: *"on Saturday **night** I go to bed early"*
>    Native speakers would almost never omit ***go to*** in the above construction, but (rarely) it might occur in a "non-habitual" context...
>    *“There will be music until God knows how late,” Selma was saying. “So [we must sleep early tonight"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YoU7doIS0q0C&pg=PA113&dq=%22sleep%20early%20tonight%22%20-%22go%20to%20sleep%22%20-%22get%20to%20sleep%22%20-%22went%20to%20sleep%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FHqEU598hb88tpOByAo&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22sleep%20early%20tonight%22%20-%22go%20to%20sleep%22%20-%22get%20to%20sleep%22%20-%22went%20to%20sleep%22&f=false).*
>
> 2: [whimsical reversal of] *"I usually sleep **late** on Saturdays"*
>    Meaning: *"on Saturday **morning** I get up early"*
>    Because of potential confusion with #1 above, this form would be unlikely unless there was a clear contextual contrast with the idiomatically standard ***late*** version.

If OP's example was *known for certain* to have been produced by a native speaker, #1 would be the most likely interpretation if it was from more than a century ago. If more recent, it's probably #2.

---

But given both of those are so unlikely, and taking account of other [howlers](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/howler) I've seen cited from online coursework here and on ELU, I would say the only real meaning to be extracted from OP's citation is that his source material came from a non-native speaker. My recommendation would be to discard it.

Comment: Agreed on all points. It's a fine sentence, structurally. I just don't know what it is supposed to mean.

Comment: [whimsical reversal of] "I usually sleep late on Saturdays"
Meaning: "on Saturday morning I get up early" - I don't get it how 'sleep late' can mean "on Saturday morning I get up early" when "sleep late" actually means to sleep more than one normally would.. @FumbleFingers

Comment: @Yukatan, you are correct that *Sleep late* means I sleep longer than usual and get up later than usual; but we are defining *Sleep Early* as the reverse of *sleep late*, so *Sleep Early* is what means to sleep less than usual and get up sooner than usual.

Comment: @Preston: Given that OP says it's from a "coursebook", it's more or less certain that what it "means" is as described in my final paragraph. That's because although it's *possible* to imagine a native speaker using those words in either of the senses I've given, in practice they would ***never*** cite it as an example in an educational context. It looks to me like a daft example from a non-native speaker who shouldn't be teaching English, but I can't 100% rule out the possibility that some Indian English speakers may find it acceptable.

Comment: I am a native speaker from Southern California who now lives in the Northeast, and to me, *I sleep around midnight* is as natural as *I have to catch the 8:04 train because I work at 9* or *I vacation in Mexico most winters*. Perhaps it relates to whether you think of *sleep* as a state or as an activity, as I agree that *I class at 3*  makes no sense, while *I lunch at noon* is acceptable but sounds old-fashioned or pretentious.

Comment: @choster: It seems pretty clear there are several native speakers here on ELL who *don't* find ***sleep early*** "unnatural". But surely no-one will be surprised at these Google Books figures - ["usually sleep early"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22usually+sleep+early%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):6, ["usually sleep late"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22usually+sleep+late%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):824. In the first it means *go to sleep / **start** sleeping*, whereas in the second it means ***stop** sleeping*. So imho it's *not* a good "usage example" in TEFL contexts.